# why location manager is null

Tags: android

WHY myLocationManager is null.explanation will be appreciated

```
package com.commonsware.android.geoweb;

    import android.app.Activity;        
    import android.content.Context;             
    import android.os.Bundle;                
    import android.location.Location;        
    import android.location.LocationListener;       
    import android.location.LocationManager;         
    import android.webkit.WebView;    
    import org.json.JSONException;    
    import org.json.JSONObject;    

    public class GeoWebOne extends Activity {
      private static String PROVIDER=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
      private WebView browser;
      private LocationManager myLocationManager=null;
```

Comment: I must admit this is a funny question.

Comment: @EmilAdz Until you realise this is not his code, it is taken from CW-Android, see e.g. http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/1116479
He is asking why in this example the LocationManager is set to `null`.

Comment: Are you asking **where** it is set to null (in the last line of the code) or **why** it is set to null?  In the latter case, most probably to indicate to code further down the program that `myLocationManager` is not (yet) instantiated.

Comment: @JosephEarl, if this is the file he took the code from the it's clearly undestood that myLocation manager is initialize in this line after myLocationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); if the question is why it is set to null then fvu is right. an indication of this object as nut yet initialized, although I would prefer your option.

Comment: I should add that according to [the JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#15858) initializing an instance var to null is done implicitly (and needs not to be done explicitly as shown here), not sure if that's true for Dalvik though.

Comment: It just is. Why can't you give `LocationManager` a break! Why does everyone always have to be picking on `LocationManager` about his state all the time? You're null! You're not null! Argggggg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to explicitly set `myLocationManager` to null in the class

```
public class GeoWebOne extends Activity {
  private static String PROVIDER=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
  private WebView browser;
  private LocationManager myLocationManager;
```

Would have worked just as well; and is probably slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set it to null here?

```
private LocationManager myLocationManager=null;
```

Comment: Also, in the complete file (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/WebKit/GeoWeb1/src/com/commonsware/android/geoweb/GeoWebOne.java), `myLocationManager` is initialized in `onCreate()` of the activity.